# How do you define a mix task in an exs file and still run it the same?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

If I had a mix task such as the following defined in hello.ex, it runs fine.

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.Hello do
  use Mix.Task
  def run(_), do: IO.puts "hello"
end
```

But this doesn't seem possible in a "hello.exs" type file? Or is there a way to have a mix task without the ".ex" extension.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what do you mean by “without compilation.” *Elixir* is indeed a compiled language, it’s unable to execute anything without compilation.

> In addition to the Elixir file extension `.ex`, Elixir also supports `.exs` files for scripting. Elixir treats both files exactly the same way, the only difference is in intention. `.ex` files are meant to be compiled while `.exs` files are used for scripting. **When executed, both extensions compile and load their modules into memory**, although only `.ex` files write their bytecode to disk in the format of `.beam` files.
>   <sub>— https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/modules-and-functions.html#scripted-mode</sub>

`mix` is an external application to your code. It requires a `.beam` file to execute it, or it has to *load the compiled script into its process memory*.

So, technically you might do somewhat like

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.Hello do
  use Mix.Task
  def run(_), do: IO.puts "hello"
end

defmodule Mix.Tasks.Wrapper do
  use Mix.Task
  def run(task) do
    Code.compile_file("hello.exs")
    Mix.Task.run(Module.concat(task))
  end
end
```

But *why*? What would be wrong with having the task as `.ex` file?

Also, you might achieve something similar with a help of [`Code.compile_string/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Code.html#compile_string/2)  to compile the task and load it into `mix` process’ memory, but again, that’s not how it’s intended to be used.

Comment: Edited ?...I meant ".ex" file not "compiled". One thing that seemed to be happening was that if I changed a function in a ".ex" file, say Hello#hello_world/1 (e.g., changed the output of IO.puts/1), I would have to manually recompile to get the changes to register. If I made a ".exs" script, the changes seemed to register.

Comment: Eh. You are not supposed to change `mix` tasks frequently :) Use arguments if you need to have a configurable behavior. Also, if you need to manually recompile something, you should fix your configuration (possibly in `mix.exs`.) When properly configured, the project does not require manual recompilation, no matter what.

Comment: But still, `foo.exs` _gets recompiled_, but you don’t get `.beam` file back and the changed bytecode is living inside your process (`iex` or whatever.) `mix`, being a different process / application has to recompile the script on its own _to get the bytecode into its memory_. There is no magic.

Comment: If I made a change to the mix task function in a ".ex" file, shouldn't Elixir pick up on the changes and recompile when I run "mix hello whatever task"? I was having to essentially remove the .beam file(s) to get Elixir to recompile.

Comment: With `Code.compile_string/2` I mentioned above you might get the bytecode of anything inside your currently running process instantly, but I doubt it’s a good way to write maintainable code.

Comment: “I was having to essentially remove the .beam file(s) to get Elixir to recompile.”—that should not happen. Make sure your task source code is located under the directory specified in `mix.exs` as a path to be compiled.